# What is similar to ViewWillAppear of objective-c for React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-props, viewwillappear

I'm using Navigation.startTabBasedApp and for each tab, componentDidMount() only calls one on app start. I want to trigger some method when user taps on particular tab. Even componentWillReceiveProps() is not getting called.

Comment: What is the navigation library you are using?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Navigation.startTabBasedApp() method of 'react-native-navigation' library